# is Allah Capable of creating a clone of himself?

Tags: islamic-philosophy

By my understanding Allah is Capable of doing anything that Allah Wish to do. is Allah Capable of Creating a clone of himself?

Answer (score 3):

"Capable of doing anything" doesn't go into the realm of insanity and irrationality.

Let me show you how it is irrational:

Allah (ﷻ)  by His Essence is **Uncreated**. There was no one before Him to create Him.

> هو الأول والآخر (He is the First and the Last) - Qur'an 57:3

To create a clone [which currently is non-existent] means this clone would have a beginning, thus it would (1) not be God by definition = couldn't be a clone and (2) would not be God's Equal (clones are usually deemed identical) = couldn't be a clone.

So it is rationally not possible for God to have a clone.

**What is irrational is not real.**

Hope this helps.

> ولم يكن له كفوا أحد (Nor is there to Him any equivalent) - Qur'an 112:4

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Friend.

I understand, act of cloning themselves(Allah) doesn't make sense. I also understand it clearly violates the definition of Allah. Question is not about whether it makes Sense. It's about whether Allah is Capable of doing such action?

These logical constraints can apply to Humans, will it also apply to Allah. I understand Allah is not Comparable to anything, but even Allah can't undo the fact that made by them(Allah).

Comment: The point is that your question isn't real and isn't applicable to Allah to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

first of all I'm not a professional I'm just putting my own opinion it is that There's no actually need of creating a drone why will he ?
It's just no sense at all ! And I agree with this that there's only one master Allah , so why does he needs a clone ! So just pray to Allah that's all ! 
May Allah bless you !